# How to mock response from integrated service while testing server

Tags: python, testing, mocking

The long story short is I am working on building a server that serves as something as a chat bot. The server uses google dialog flow. Right now I have an endpoint exposed that allows me to talk to my server, when I hit that endpoint, google auth, as well as google dialog flow gets called. I am attempting to mock the response of dialog flow while leaving the actual server to respond to the network call. As of now my test looks like this.

This is my base test file:

```
import unittest
import mock


class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase, object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseTest, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)

    def auto_patch(self, patch_target):
        patcher = mock.patch(patch_target)
        patched = patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        return patched
```

This is my test file:

```
import json
import uuid
from os import path
from tests.base_test import BaseTest
from agent.api_service import app
import requests_mock
import pytest
from hamcrest import assert_that, has_items, equal_to

CWD = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))


class TestAudio(BaseTest):
    def test__interact__full_no_stt(self):
        payload = json.load(open("tests/json_payloads/test__interact__full_audio.json"))
        u_session_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        payload["session_id"] = u_session_id

        #mock a 500 back from STT
        with open("tests/json_payloads/stt_500.json", "r") as issues_file:
            mock_response = issues_file.read()

        with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
            m.register_uri('POST', 'https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize', text=mock_response)



        request, response = app.test_client.post("/agent_service/interact", data=json.dumps(payload))
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status)
```

This is my google stt file:

```
import json
import requests
from agent.exceptions import GoogleSTTException
from agent.integrations.google.google_auth_service import get_auth_token
from agent.integrations.google.google_stt_request import GoogleSTTRequest
from agent.integrations.google.google_stt_response import GoogleSTTResponse


def speech_to_text(audio_string):
    try:
        google_stt_request = GoogleSTTRequest(audio_string).to_payload()

        request_headers = dict()
        request_headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + get_auth_token()
        request_headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

        url = 'https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize'
        google_response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(google_stt_request), headers=request_headers)
        response = GoogleSTTResponse(google_response.json())
        return response

    except Exception as e:
        raise GoogleSTTException('Received an error invoking google stt {}'.format(e))
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can mock the response from the google stt call, without touching the google auth call or the server call itself? I have tried a handful of things and so far no luck. I either end up mocking nothing, or both the google stt and auth call.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up moving away from the original implementation, but this is what got me there.

```
    @responses.activate
    def test__interact__full_no_stt(self):
        payload = json.load(open("tests/json_payloads/test__interact__full_audio.json"))
        u_session_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        payload["session_id"] = u_session_id

        #mock a 500 back from STT
        responses.add(responses.POST,
                      'https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize',
                      json={'error': 'broken'}, status=500)



        request, response = app.test_client.post("/agent_service/interact", data=json.dumps(payload))
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status)
        result = response.json
```

Responses makes this much easier, just be sure to include the annotation at the top of the test.